# vba macros load image file name into slide & not the image

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm just new here and wish your kind help please.
I had a macro add-in for PowerPoint was working fine with older versions.
The new 365 office didn't run it; and with a few tricks I was able to solve most of it.
Now the only thing left is when try to open and select image files from a folder, it loads the image name to each slide and **not** the images!

```
Sub Insert1PicViaForm()

' Added on 21.05.06 to load single file using code from
'
'  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnovba00/html/CommonDialogsPartI.asp
'
'
Dim OFN As OPENFILENAME
Dim Ret
Dim N As Integer
Dim ddd
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oPic As Shape

  With OFN
    .lStructSize = LenB(OFN)     ' Size of structure.
    .nMaxFile = 574             ' Size of buffer.
    ' Create buffer.
    .lpstrFile = String(.nMaxFile - 1, 0)
    Ret = GetOpenFileName(OFN)  ' Call function.
    If Ret <> 0 Then            ' Non-zero is success.
      ' Find first null char.
      N = InStr(.lpstrFile, vbNullChar)
      ' Return what's before it.
      ' MsgBox Left(.lpstrFile, n - 1)
      ' Full path and filename
      ddd = Left(.lpstrFile, N - 1)
      ' Add slide at end of presentation
            
      Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
      ' Insert pic as selected
      Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=ddd, _
              LinkToFile:=msoCTrue, _
              SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
              Left:=60, _
              Top:=35, _
              Width:=98, _
              Height:=48)

    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code directly, not in an image

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I tried but very limited lines show, the rest of the code gets merged badly.

Comment: Copy paste it, select it and then press Ctrl + K

Comment: Super, many thanks, I was youtubing for this, but it take longer time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks about your code:

- You're missing the `GetOpenFileName` function.
- Opening the file dialog and returning the file path is now straightforward. No need to read and buffer the picture file

Please read the code's comments and ajust it to fit your needs

```
Public Sub InsertPicture()

    ' Declare and set a variable to ask for a file
    Dim fileDialogObject As FileDialog
    Set fileDialogObject = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    ' Adjust file dialog properties
    With fileDialogObject
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Temp"
        .Title = "Insert Picture"
        .ButtonName = "Insert picture"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg,*.png,*.eps,*.tif,*.tiff", 1
    End With
    
    ' Show the file dialog to user and wait for response
    If fileDialogObject.Show = False Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Loop through each selected file (selectedFile returns the file path string)
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    For Each selectedFile In fileDialogObject.SelectedItems
    
        ' Set new slide layout
        Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
        Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
    
        ' Add a sile and reference it
        Dim newSlide As Slide
        Set newSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, pptLayout)
        
        ' Insert picture in new slide
        Dim newPicture As Shape
        Set newPicture = newSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=selectedFile, _
                        LinkToFile:=msoCTrue, _
                        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
                        Left:=60, _
                        Top:=35, _
                        Width:=98, _
                        Height:=48)
    Next selectedFile

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I just also added something for a blank slide when importing the images
Please see below. and again many thanks.

```
Public Sub InsertPicture()

    ' Declare and set a variable to ask for a file
    Dim fileDialogObject As FileDialog
    Set fileDialogObject = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    ' Adjust file dialog properties
    With fileDialogObject
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Temp"
        .Title = "Insert Picture"
        .ButtonName = "Insert picture"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg,*.png,*.eps,*.tif,*.tiff", 1
    End With
    
    ' Show the file dialog to user and wait for response
    If fileDialogObject.Show = False Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Loop through each selected file (selectedFile returns the file path string)
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    For Each selectedFile In fileDialogObject.SelectedItems
    
        ' Set new slide layout
        ' Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
        ' Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
    
        ' Add a sile and reference it
        Dim newSlide As Slide
        Set newSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
        
        ' Insert picture in new slide
        Dim newPicture As Shape
        Set newPicture = newSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=selectedFile, _
                        LinkToFile:=msoCTrue, _
                        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
                        Left:=60, _
                        Top:=35, _
                        Width:=98, _
                        Height:=48)
    Next selectedFile

End Sub
```